# How to enable detailed database connection logging?

Tags: python, django, oracle

Our DBA is trying to migrate a Django application's database to a new backend host running Oracle 12.  When I put that host's info in the Django `settings.py` file, I get this error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error
```

The DBA has asked for my help in solving this problem.  Is there a way to turn on detailed logging in Django while establishing a database connection?  I've seen directions for enabling logging of database *queries*, but we're not getting that far -- our error is happening sometime during the *connection*.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#exception-handling) the error code and message is about as much as you're going to get from `cx_Oracle` which is the interface that Django uses.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use a Wireshark or any sniffing tool to check what is the connection string passed to the DB.

But this oracle error will occur when there is an error after the initial handshake to the Oracle DB and further establishing a connection.

Check you oracle_cx for python and the oracle instant client whether the insta client is of the correct version to the DB. Try a connection form instantclient directly to the DB using sqlplus.

Reference:

[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/)

[DBA forum](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_28547_connection_to_server_failed_probable_oracle_net_admin_error.htm)

[django community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/WnLejpFfUsE)